# Куда ставится ударение

Tags: орфоэпия

Куда ставится ударение в слове микрополоски[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ударение ставится на *последнем* слоге: по существующей терминологии, в именительном падеже это "**(микро)полосОк**" **(микро)полоскОвой** линии. **Полосок** - это разновидность волновода, его образует не только геометрическая "полоска" металла на поверхности диэлектрика, а и пространство между "полоской" и нижней металлизированной стороной диэлектрика.

http://www.pcbtech.ru/volnovoe-soprotivlenie-provodnika-i-peredacha-signala

**P. S.** В ряде источников сейчас попадается и вариант "полоска" - возможно, что-то меняется со временем или так называют геометрический элемент при расчётах (здесь *оба* смысла присутствуют: https://naparah.com/elektrodinamika/0606166.html), тем не менее в слове "полоскОвый" (микрополосковый) я ни разу не слышал ударения на втором слоге.